# C# Visual Studio 2019, Meta Numeric, Error: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019
C#

Project 1:
Dependencies: Meta.Numerics 4.1.4. I added Meta Numerics via the Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
Project 1 is a Class Library
Will be compiled and .dll will be shared with an associate who will use it in the main application
Project 1 builds just fine using Debug.

```
using System;
using Meta.Numerics;

namespace LeakDetection
{
    public class LeakDetectionOperations
    {

        public LeakDetectionOperations(int co = 24)
        { }

        public int leakCheck()
        {

            double result = ComplexMath.Abs(10);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Project 2
Dependencies: Project 1. Imported via Add references, browser, and selected the .dll from project 1
Project 2 is just a simple test project that I'm using to test the .dll object.
It runs, but throws an exception when it attempts to call the ABS function of Meta.Numerics.

[image: Output image]

[image: Terminal image]

```
using System;
using LeakDetection;

namespace LeakTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LeakDetectionOperations obj = new LeakDetectionOperations();
            int ret;
            ret = obj.leakCheck();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've followed the instructions from the Meta.Numeric gitrepo regarding installation. The installation was done as they suggested to install the package. I've also cleaned build, and rebuilt fresh. I also changed from debug to release to see if there was anything related to the debug that was causing the error. As you can see at the above code, its fairly minimum, as this is not my actual code. Its a bit more elaborate, but rather than posting the full code, this is the minimum usable code that replicates the issue I'm having. Nothing from the Meta.numeric library is usable.

I usually work in Python, have some experience in C and C++, but I have used make files to compile in linux. Using C#, visual studio is fresh for me.

Any suggestions as to where I should look would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Per the suggestion by @kit, I've included the .csproj file for project 1 below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Leak_Detection</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Meta.Numerics" Version="4.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

.csproj for project 2

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Leak Detection">
      <HintPath>..\..\Leak Detection\Leak Detection\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Leak Detection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You might try adding relevant portion of  `.csproj` files to your question...

Comment: @Kit Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the post with the full .csproj file. It was small enough that it doesn't add many lines to the post, and well I have no idea what would be relevant.

Comment: I was able to create and run your minimal code with no issue. It looks like a NuGet versioning conflict of some kind (2.2.0 trying to load as shown in the console vs referencing 4.1.4 of Numerics. Try clearing your nuget cache, .vs directory, delete bin and obj directories and do a full rebuild in VS and see if that clears up the issue.

Comment: Are you using Meta.Numerics or Meta.Numerics_2.2.0.0 from the Nuget package manager?

Comment: The former. I ended up with code virtually identical to yours (csproj, cs, etc.) I noted when looking at NuGet.org that there's a Meta.Numerics with a 2.2 and 4.1.4 version, and then the Meta.Numerics_2.2.0.0 with a 1.0.0 version... definitely confusing... that's why I think something went awry there with caches and so on.

Comment: I'm still getting a file not found exception. I'm going to start from scratch and create a new workspace.

Comment: This issue is not limited to Meta.Numeric. I just tried MathNet.numerics and I'm getting the same issue. I think this is a VS issue.

Comment: If you think it's VS related, try doing a `dotnet build` to see if you get a different result.

Comment: Looking at your second project, you are referencing a DLL/assembly directly. That *is* unusual. Remove that and go into VS and add a **project reference** to project 2, rebuild and see if it works.

Comment: All the references I've found for adding a dll have been the same. right click on dependencies within the solution explorer of the project. select add reference. Browse and add the dll I want to reference. The dll now shows up under Dependencies > Assemblies. The only difference I have found from searching around that was different from how I did it, was that I didn't set 'copy local' to yes. I tried that, but did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to kind of replicate your issue (not exactly but I got the same kind of error). I believe your test project is in .NET framework. If I do not reference any nuget package in test project, failure occurs. But, if I install any nuget package and later on uninstall it, program runs successfully. For testing, I installed and uninstalled Newtonsoft.Json package. So, there is a bug in initialization of nuget package engine for .NET framework where in absence of any nuget packages, it is not able to resolve transitive nuget dependencies. If I create test project in .NET core, test project runs without any issue.

I have also put code in github
https://github.com/dheerajjain11/MissingDLLIssue/

1. MetaNumerics is .NET Standard library
2. MetaNumericsTest is .NET Framework Test project where I installed and uninstalled nuget package. Now, it runs successfully
3. MetaNumerics2 is .NET Framework Test project which fails
4. MetaCore is dotnet core project which runs without any issue and no workarounds

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your saying. I can say that the .dll project was setup as a Class Library (.NET Standard) when I created the project. The Text application I created in a separate window as Console App (.NET Core). I know there's an option for (.NET Framework), but I didn't select that option.  I've set up the application twice now, with the same result.

Comment: So I'm begging to think this is an issue with my VS. As I just tried another package that has a similiar function I'm looking for and I'm getting the same issue. MathNet.Numeric is generating the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is normal or not, but what resolved the issue for me was installing the package via the Nuget package manager on both the Library and the Console application. Both builds need a reference.

What I was doing previously, was only installing the package for the library build. Seeing how the console application was then compiling with the .dll being referenced and called, the calling application also needed the package installed.

Comment: I just noticed that you didn't show the .csproj for project 2, which you stated had the problem. What you're describing in your answer seems to indicate some sort of transitive packages problem. Your solution here basically works around that. Perhaps add second project info to your question, and then we can get you a canonical answer. What you did is still in the realm of "normal" but ordinarily shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Hey @Kit, I've updated the original post with the MUC for both project 1 and 2, and additional I've added the .csproj for both at the end, pre work around. The work around is doing what its suppose to do, but my concern is when I ship the .dll off to our client, is it going to be easily imported or are they going to have to do the same fix I had

Comment: See my comment on your question. I think I see a possible issue.